# C# Math.Ceiling rounds up a event double... (500 to 501) (formula)

Tags: c#, excel, math, double, ceil

why rounds C# this calculation up?

500 -> 501

```
MessageBox.Show(Math.Ceiling(1 / (4 * 1 - 4 * 0.9) * 200).ToString());
```

Returns.

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
501
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I dont know why.

Excel doesnt do this, too.

[image: Excel doesnt round the formula up.]

I need the ceiling function for the fomula which returns 500 instead 501.

I could use this instead. But i would know if there is another solution and why C# do this.

```
MessageBox.Show(Math.Ceiling(Math.Floor((1 / (4 * 1 - 4 * 0.9) * 200) * 100) / 100).ToString());
```

Comment: Because binary floating point numbers....

Comment: Hmm. But is there a other solution or a function where i can say that ceiling should use only the last 2 decimals?

Comment: @PatrickKaiser Just use ``decimal``.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `500` is **actually not** `500` but rather `500.0000000001` (or something similar) due to using floating point operations.

To solve this issue, use `decimal` instead of `double`.

```
MessageBox.Show(Math.Ceiling(1.0M / (4.0M * 1.0M - 4.0M * 0.9M) * 200.0M).ToString());
```

---

See [What every Computer Scientist should know about Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf) for further information, or take a look at [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) website for a simpler explanation.